# Cant install blotter package

Tags: r, quantstrat, blotter

Im at a complete loss and have tried several solutions suggested by others on StackOverflow.
I struggled to install quanstrat and eventually managed to get thsi sorted out with @MrFlick's help. However, quanstrat needs the package blotter to be installed. I have tried several ways of doing this via source, uploading the zip files, installing other packages.. nothing works.
Any suggestions will be welcome. (similar issues with Rtools?)

Could also not install Rtools as suggested, for the same reason.R version issue?

Comment: If you are working on Windows, did you install `Rtools` as [suggested](http://www.programmingr.com/content/installing-quantstrat-r-forge-and-source/)?

Comment: @Pascal. I am incurring the same problem with installing Rtools as with blotter. i note from muc of the communication that Rtools now has a version 33 that also requires modification to install. not sure how to do this.